# Sync slider (Slick Slider)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

Мучаюсь с этим слайдером уже неделю. Должно получиться как на изображении:

[image: Должно выглядеть так]
Загрузила с Slick SLider - Sync. Вставила в сетку, задала картинкам фиксированный размер.

И тут понеслось, в браузере через f12 блок slick-track выходит за разрешение окна. Плюс не могу понять почему маленькая картинка слайдера полностью съезжает, плюс из-за слайдера появляются внутренние отступы, из-за которых по ширине картинку не получается вытянуть...

Помогите, вообще не понимаю как с этим работать

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    draggable: false
  });
  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    arrows: true,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    draggable: false,
    infinite: false,
    prevArrow: '<img class="larrow-gallery" src="images/gallery/larrow-gallery.svg">',
    nextArrow: '<img class="rarrow-gallery" src="images/gallery/rarrow-gallery.svg">'
  });
});
```

```css
galery {
  grid-row: 5/6;
  display: grid;
  grid: auto/auto;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider-for {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  height: 41vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.slider-for2 {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 40.5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(0.2vw);
}

.slider-for2>img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.border-slider-nav {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 41vh;
  background-color: #829329;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 90% 0%, 80% 100%, 10% 100%);
  display: grid;
  grid: repeat(2, auto)/auto;
  position: absolute;
  grid-row-gap: 2vh;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#border-slider-name {
  margin: 2vh 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-family: Roboto Slab;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  color: #E7DECD;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.slider-nav2>img {
  width: 28vw;
  height: 28vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0.5vw solid #E7DECD;
}

.slider-nav2 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.slider-nav {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  display: grid;
  grid: auto/auto;
}

.larrow-gallery {
  left: -14%;
}

.rarrow-gallery {
  right: -14%;
}

.larrow-gallery,
.rarrow-gallery {
  width: 3vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<galery>
  <div class="slider-for">
    <div class="slider-for2"><img src="images/gallery/1.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="slider-for2"><img src="images/gallery/2.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="slider-for2"><img src="images/gallery/3.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="slider-for2"><img src="images/gallery/4.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-slider-nav">
    <p id="border-slider-name">Примеры работ</p>
    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div class="slider-nav2"><img src="images/gallery/1a.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider-nav2"><img src="images/gallery/2a.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider-nav2"><img src="images/gallery/3a.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider-nav2"><img src="images/gallery/4a.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
  <script src="sync-slider.js"></script>
</galery>
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов,  да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо определиться с выбором технологии: либо гриды, либо флексы. Смешивая их, вы сами себя запутываете.

В примере ниже были выбраны флексы и созданы два вспомогательных блока: один слева, другой - справа, потому что так проще отцентрировать лицевой слайдер. Задаём этим блокам, помимо одинаковой ширины, внешние отступы `margin-left: auto;` для левого и `margin-right: auto;` для правого. Далее, уже индивидуально при помощи `clip-path` обрезаем их отображение.

Фоновый слайдер имеет абсолютное позиционирование, поэтому просто скрываем лишнее при переполнении родительского контейнера `overflow: hidden;`.

```js
$('#front-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '#background-slider',
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  infinite: true,
  nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next">Next</button>',
  prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev">Previous</button>',
});

$('#background-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  draggable: false,
  fade: true,
  focusOnSelect: false,
});
```

```css
:root {
  --dark: #222;
  --gray-dark: #333;
  --gray: #888;
  --light: #eee;
  --white: #fff;
  --green: #819329;
  --primary: var(--green);
}

body {
  background: var(--light);
}

.page {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 2.5rem auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.left-slider-helper,
.right-slider-helper {
  width: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: var(--primary);
}

.left-slider-helper {
  margin-left: auto;
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.right-slider-helper {
  margin-right: auto;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.front-slider-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: var(--white);
}

.front-slider-inner .slick-slider {
  border: 1px solid var(--light);
  padding: 4px;
  background: var(--white);
}

.background-slider-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Стили плагина -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="page">
  <div class="left-slider-helper"></div>

  <div class="front-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="front-slider-inner">
      <h3>Примеры работ</h3>
      <div id="front-slider" class="slider">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/ff9ff3/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+1" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/feca57/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+2" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/ff6b6b/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+3" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/48dbfb/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+4" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/1dd1a1/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+5" />
      </div>
      <p>Описание текущей работы</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-slider-helper"></div>

  <div class="background-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="background-slider-inner">
      <div id="background-slider" class="slider">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/ff9ff3/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+1" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/feca57/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+2" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/ff6b6b/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+3" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/48dbfb/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+4" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/1dd1a1/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+5" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Скрипты плагина-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое